# Asp.net displaying the same date in two ajax calendar_extender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a problem with some ajax calendar extenders. I have similiar 2 calendars and two textboxes that are each linked to one calendar.

```
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"</asp:TextBox>
                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calendar1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt1"
                        Format="yyyy-MM-dd" CssClass="Calendars" Enabled="false">
```

When I select a date in the first calendar, I want the second calendar to place itself in the same month as the first calendar but **without selecting the actual date** (because doing so will make the txt2 display that date). The txt2 textbox should remain empty until a date is selected by the user in calendar2.

I have look everywhere on the internet but nothing seems to fit that situation.

can anybody help?

EDIT:

I have tried to change the date and then erase the textbox with javascript but I have a compare validator that triggers when I do so. I use the following javascript code to erase the textbox:

```
        function onShowingCal2(sender, e) {
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('<%= txt2.ClientID %>');
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%= txt1.ClientID %>');
        var cal2 = sender;
        if (txt2.value == "") {
            var dateStart = new Date();
            dateStart.setDate(txt1.value);
            cal2.set_selectedDate(dateStart );
            datechosen = false;                
        }
    }
function onTextboxChange() {
            if (!datechosen ) {
                document.getElementById('<%= txt2.ClientID %>').value = "";
            }
        }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly got something working

What I did is I took the javascript code in the question and added one very simple function:

```
        function EndDateChosen(e) {
        dateChosen = true;
    }
```

And call this like so in the calendar2 tag's property OnClientDateSelectionChanged='EndDateChosen'

that event was a pain to make work. The javascript fonction HAS to have ONLY one parameter and the fonction name in the calendar's tag HAS to be surrounded with single quotes not doubleQuotes.

thanks yall!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can set the `SelectedDate` property of `calendar2` but clear the text of `txt2`?

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

There are some client event of Calendar you can use.

```
OnClientDateSelectionChanged    OnClientHidden    OnClientHiding
```

For example, you can define `OnClientDateSelectionChanged="onSelectChanged()`".

```
function onSelectChanged()
{
     alert($find('calendar1')._selectedDate);
}
```

So your code will become:

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calendar1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt1" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" CssClass="Calendars" Enabled="false" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="onSelectChanged()">

function onSelectChanged()
{
   $find('calendar2')._selectedDate = $find('calendar1')._selectedDate;
}
```

Comment: I tried but I have a comparevalidator that is triggered when I do so, and An error message is displayed even if the textbox appears empty.

Comment: how do you do it? I meant doing it on the client through script.

Comment: hmm, interesting, instead of trying to change the value of txt2, try `$find('calendar2')._selectedDate = $find('calendar1')._selectedDate;`

Comment: I also tried it but the problem is both calendar are nerver displayed at the same time so I can't do $find('calendar1') and $find('calendar2') at the same time because $find only get the element shown in the screen

Comment: I believe better to employ `get` and `set` functions instead of direct access to `_selectedDate` field: `$find('calendar2').set_selectedDate($find('calendar1').get_selectedDate())`

Comment: store `$find('calendar1')._selectedDate` in a variable `date1`, add an OnClientClick event on calendar2 and store the value of `date1` in `$find('calendar2')._selectedDate`

Comment: And also, in `onSelectChanged` function you can access sender extender from first parameter: `function onSelectChanged(sender, args){ alert(sender.get_selectedDate()); }`

Comment: I ended up with something I'll mark it as anwser in 2 days thanks al lot!